# Work done by isothermal gas expansion followed by an isobaric expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

> A mono-atomic ideal gas of $2$ moles undergoes an isothermal expansion which makes its volume double. Then the volume of the gas is doubled again through an isobaric process. Given a starting temperature of $350$ Kelvin:
>
> - how much work is done by the gas during the isobaric expansion?
> - how much heat is transferred during the isothermal expansion?
>
> *note*: R = $8.31$ *J/(mol*K)* and Cp = $5/2$ * R

The problem gives me this data:

- $n$ = 2 *mol*
- $T_1$ = $350$ *K*
- $R$ = $8.31$ *J/(mol*K)*
- $C_p$ = $\frac5 2$ $R$
- $V_3 = 2V_2 = 4V_1$

This is the pressure-volume diagram:
[image: Pressure–volume diagram]

The formula that I would use to find the work for the isobaric expansion would be $W = nR(T_3 - T_2)$

But I don't know how to find the temperature at the end of the expansion, because the problem doesn't give me pressure or volume. So I can't use $P_iV_i = nRT_i$ to start finding it.
I don't know if I'm missing something very important or the problem is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is enough information to solve this.  $$W=P_2(V_3-V_2)$$together with $$P_2=\frac{nRT_2}{V_2}=\frac{nRT_1}{V_2}$$So $$W=\frac{nRT_1}{V_2}(V_3-V_2)=nRT_1\left(\frac{V_3}{V_2}-1\right)=nRT_1$$

Answer (score 1):

"I'm missing something very important or the problem is wrong". There isn't enough information to find  numerical values for $p_1$ or $V_1$ separately. But all the other pressures and volumes can easily be expressed in terms of $V_1$. Leave $V_1$ in your workings out, and you'll find it cancels out, so you can give numerical answers to the questions.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already perfectly answered, but I thought i'd add a little bit starting with the first law as I personally found it very helpful to get some sort of intuition for problems of this kind:

$$dU=dQ+W_s$$

From State 1 to State 2:

Since
$$dU=c_v * dT$$ 
and the process is isothermal, $dU=0$ and so $dQ = - W_s$

Now by using the ideal gas law:

$$W_{s12}= -\int pdV = -nRT_1*ln\frac{2V_1}{
V_1}=-nRT_1*ln(2)$$

State 2 to State 3:

Since $p*V = const$, the pressure of State 2 is

$$p_2=\frac{p_1*V_1}{2V_1} =\frac{p_1}{2}$$

the process is isobaric, so the shaft work simplifies to

$$W_{s23}= -\int pdV = p_2*\Delta V = \frac{p_1}{2} * (4V_1-2V_1) =
p_1*V_1 $$

So in terms of known quantities
$$W_{s23}=nRT_1$$